# How to implement slider/progressbar for video app, YouTube style?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to implement slider/progressbar like YouTube style. That means when mouse on the progressbar the tooltip show the time position exactly. How can I do that?
Should I use Slider? or perhaps ProgressBar?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I posted a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178134/wpf-adding-a-tooltip-to-the-track-of-a-slider/46049638#46049638

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please look into the jobi's link for the slider previews may this can help you

http://jobijoy.blogspot.com/2009/07/attaching-preview-behavior-to-wpf.html

Comment: Unfortunately the source code link is broken. Could you please provide another source or paste the code of the behavior and its usage here?

Answer (score 0):

I want to revisit this question in 2013. As of Aug 13, 2013 youtube has a progress bar implemented at the top of the website. A redline crosses the screen from left to right at the place where the browser(probably bookmark bar for some) meets the actual website.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this @Rakhilya, i am interested in the redline too....